# Protractor errors

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I've been struggling with protractor with quite a few hours now, and I haven't even been able to run my first test. To start it, I'm using `npm run e2e`, which produces the following errors:

```
  ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
[1] npm ERR! errno 1
[1] npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 protractor: `protractor 
protractor.config.js`
[1] npm ERR! Exit status 1
[1] npm ERR!
[1] npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 protractor script 'protractor protractor.config.js'.
[1] npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
[1] npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
[1] npm ERR! not with npm itself.
[1] npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
[1] npm ERR!     protractor protractor.config.js
[1] npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
[1] npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
[1] npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
[1] npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
[1] npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
[1]
[1] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
[1] npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-05-08T22_41_36_233Z-debug.log
[1] npm run protractor exited with code 1
--> Sending SIGTERM to other processes..
[0] npm run serve:e2e exited with code 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! angular-quickstart@1.0.0 e2e: `concurrently "npm run serve:e2e" "npm 
run protractor" --kill-others --success first`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 e2e script 'concurrently "npm 
run serve:e2e" "npm run protractor" --kill-others --success first'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart 
package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     concurrently "npm run serve:e2e" "npm run protractor" --kill-others --success first
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-05-
08T22_24_18_355Z-debug.log
```

I have absolutely no idea what to do at this point. What can I do to fix this this error? I have updated both nodes.js and npm. Their versions are now 6.10.3 and 4.5.0 respectively.

Also, I don't know if I'm supposed to have 2 config files. I found a guide that told me to create a `config.js` file, which I did in my `e2e` folder. I also found a `protractor.config.js` file that I guess was in the angular-quickstart project by default. Are both required, or should i delete the `conf.js`?

Here's the content of the log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Users\\Jesper\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'e2e' ]
2 info using npm@4.5.0
3 info using node@v6.10.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'pree2e', 'e2e', 'poste2e' ]
5 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~pree2e: angular-quickstart@1.0.0
6 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~pree2e: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
7 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~pree2e: PATH: C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Jesper\Documents\GitHub\StudentDatabaseFrontEnd\Student Database\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin
8 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~pree2e: CWD: C:\Users\Jesper\Documents\GitHub\StudentDatabaseFrontEnd\Student Database
9 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~pree2e: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run build:e2e' ]
10 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~pree2e: Returned: code: 0  signal: null
11 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~e2e: angular-quickstart@1.0.0
12 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~e2e: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
13 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~e2e: PATH: C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\Jesper\Documents\GitHub\StudentDatabaseFrontEnd\Student Database\node_modules\.bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\bin
14 verbose lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~e2e: CWD: C:\Users\Jesper\Documents\GitHub\StudentDatabaseFrontEnd\Student Database
15 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~e2e: Args: [ '/d /s /c',
15 silly lifecycle   'concurrently "npm run serve:e2e" "npm run protractor" --kill-others --success first' ]
16 silly lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~e2e: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
17 info lifecycle angular-quickstart@1.0.0~e2e: Failed to exec e2e script
18 verbose stack Error: angular-quickstart@1.0.0 e2e: `concurrently "npm run serve:e2e" "npm run protractor" --kill-others --success first`
18 verbose stack Exit status 1
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\lifecycle.js:279:16)
18 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
18 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:191:7)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Jesper\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\spawn.js:40:14)
18 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
18 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
18 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:886:16)
18 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:226:5)
19 verbose pkgid angular-quickstart@1.0.0
20 verbose cwd C:\Users\Jesper\Documents\GitHub\StudentDatabaseFrontEnd\Student Database\e2e
21 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.14393
22 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Jesper\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "e2e"
23 verbose node v6.10.3
24 verbose npm  v4.5.0
25 error code ELIFECYCLE
26 error errno 1
27 error angular-quickstart@1.0.0 e2e: `concurrently "npm run serve:e2e" "npm run protractor" --kill-others --success first`
27 error Exit status 1
28 error Failed at the angular-quickstart@1.0.0 e2e script 'concurrently "npm run serve:e2e" "npm run protractor" --kill-others --success first'.
28 error Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
28 error If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular-quickstart package,
28 error not with npm itself.
28 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
28 error     concurrently "npm run serve:e2e" "npm run protractor" --kill-others --success first
28 error You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
28 error     npm bugs angular-quickstart
28 error Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
28 error     npm owner ls angular-quickstart
28 error There is likely additional logging output above.
29 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

And here's my folder structure:

[image]

Comment: could you paster the content of package.json at here?  from the debug.log there are configured some pre-steps in package.json before running test script.  the failure should be caused by those pre-steps.

Answer (score 0):

From what I could figure out, the error messages are supposed to appear when a test has failed, but I'm not sure why. It might be confusing for new users like me who think there's something wrong.

Comment: this ELIFECYCLE error is thrown by running your protractor suite with `npm`. It makes for a super messy log, but its expected if your protractor has even 1 failed test case.

Answer (score 0):

your best bet would be to read the basics, I recomend this site: 
http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/protractor-testing-tutorial/

You need two files to start your Protractor test. One file is conf.js, the other is the one where you store your test (spec.js, test.spec.js). Make sure that in your conf file you wrote the right spec file name:

```
// conf.js
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js'] //spec file name
}
```